# MySQL query running slow what is the bottleneck

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a MySQL query which ran for 22 seconds, I have added the index for all the select and where condition. the usage table has about 79000 records. The labels table has 602173 records. I tried to optimized it by adding index. Is that the join statements that make it slow. Or any index I should implemented to increase the speed of the stored procedure. But it still running slow. May I know where is the bottleneck and how I can improve it?

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SelectUsage2`(          
      IN p_ids MEDIUMTEXT
    , IN p_locationIDs MEDIUMTEXT
    , IN p_indicatorIDs MEDIUMTEXT        
    )
BEGIN
    select 
        , case when (select count(lbl.id) from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = i.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'indicators' and lbl.ColumnName = 'IndicatorName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language) > 0 then
            (select content from `labels` as lbl where lbl.ObjectID = i.id and lbl.ObjectName = 'indicators' and lbl.ColumnName = 'IndicatorName' and lbl.LanguageCode = p_language limit 1)
        else
            i.IndicatorName
        end as IndicatorName
        u.*          
    from
        `usage` as u
        left join `locations` as l on u.LocationID = l.id
        left join `Indicators` as i on u.IndicatorID = i.id
        left join `Indicators` as i2 on i.ParentID = i2.id
    where           
        and (p_ids is null or FIND_IN_SET(u.id, p_ids))
        and (p_locationIDs is null or FIND_IN_SET(u.LocationID, p_locationIDs))
        and (p_indicatorIDs is null or FIND_IN_SET(u.IndicatorID, p_indicatorIDs))
    order by
        i.IndicatorName, l.LocationName
;    
END
```

Comment: sorry, but are you paid to optimize the query XD? joke aside, personally i cant help much, but things you need consider are: 1) too many key can be a bad thing, 2) understand what the query trying to achieve, is it the shortest? 3) take a peek on the query plan

Comment: If it was me, I'd start over. With that in mind, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks , I will edit the question.

Comment: The query plan will help decide where to start, but I would think carefully about the queries nested in the case statements--is there a more efficient way to get that information?